# IF function returning TRUE/FALSE instead of referenced cell values

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

I am on LibreOffice Calc 5 (Ubuntu 16.04). When I enter "`=IF(AA2<=4, X2, 0)`", what I expect is that it should return the value in cell 'X2' or '0'. But instead it is returning only TRUE/FALSE. Does it look like some bug? Please let me know how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the formatting of the cell. It may be formatted to display boolean values only instead of the literal formula result.

You can set such a formatting using the cell's context menu -> "Format Cells...", or Menu "Format" -> "Cells...".

To **make sure no formatting is applied to the result**, right-click on the cell containing the formula, and **select "*Clear direct formatting*":**

[image]

Comment: Yes. Direct formatting was the issue. It did work!

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `=IF(AA2<=4;X2;0)`. Note the semicolons instead of commas.

Comment: The syntax depends on the localization settings - so commas _may_ be correct. Additionally, wrong separators would yield an `Err: 509` instead of `TRUE`/`FALSE`.